# Export automatically in laravel excel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8, laravel-excel

I have a doubt and I don't know how to send a parameter so that the collection function of my export generates an excel with that data.
I generate this query through a method of one of my controllers

The controller is GenerateNumbersController.php and the method is validateNumberBD

The query I generate is as follows:

```php
$searchOrCreate = Phone::insertIgnore($consultArray);

if ($searchOrCreate) {
    $phones = Phone::select('PHONES.PHONE','AREACODES.CODE')
    ->join('AREACODES','AREACODES.AREACODES_ID','=','PHONES.AREACODES_ID')
    ->where('DATE',$searchOrCreate)
    ->get();
}
```

That query generates a collection of data that is what I need to send to be exported automatically.

This is where my problem begins since I don't know how to send that variable to the PhonesExport class, which is the class that generates exports to Exce

I tried to create a new function in the PhonesExport class called data ($ value) as follows:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use App\Http\Controllers;

class PhonesExport implements FromCollection
{   
    public $data;

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    public function collection()
    {
        global $data;       
        return $data;
    }

    public function data($dato)
    {
        global $data;
        $data = $dato;
    }
}
```

And through the method of the first code try to generate an instance of that class, and then send it by the same parameter as follows.

```php
$searchOrCreate = Phone::insertIgnore($consultArray);

if ($searchOrCreate) {
    $phones = Phone::select('PHONES.PHONE','AREACODES.CODE')
    ->join('AREACODES','AREACODES.AREACODES_ID','=','PHONES.AREACODES_ID')
    ->where('DATE',$searchOrCreate)
    ->get();    

    $excel = new PhonesExport();
    $excel->data($phones );

    \Excel::download($excel,'phones.xlsx');
}
```

But when executing it generates nothing to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option 1: Use Dependency Injection.

```php
$searchOrCreate = Phone::insertIgnore($consultArray);
if ($searchOrCreate) {
    $phones = Phone::select('PHONES.PHONE','AREACODES.CODE')
    ->join('AREACODES','AREACODES.AREACODES_ID','=','PHONES.AREACODES_ID')
    ->where('DATE',$searchOrCreate)
    ->get();    

    $excel = new PhonesExport($phones);

    \Excel::download($excel,'phones.xlsx');
}
```

```php
namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class PhonesExport implements FromCollection
{
    protected $phones;

    public function __construct($phones)
    {
       $this->phones = $phones;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function collection()
    {
       return $this->phones;
    }
}
```

## Option 2: Move the query to the Exporter class.

```php
$searchOrCreate = Phone::insertIgnore($consultArray);
if ($searchOrCreate) {    
    $excel = new PhonesExport($searchOrCreate);

    \Excel::download($excel,'phones.xlsx');
}
```

```php
namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use App\Phone;

class PhonesExport implements FromCollection
{
    protected $date;

    public function __construct($date)
    {
       $this->date = $date;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function collection()
    {
       return Phone::select('PHONES.PHONE','AREACODES.CODE')
       ->join('AREACODES','AREACODES.AREACODES_ID','=','PHONES.AREACODES_ID')
       ->where('DATE', $this->date)
       ->get();
    }
}
```

## Option 3: Force Download with readfile.

Instead of calling `\Excel::download(...)`, call `\Excel::store(...)` and then return a download to the file.

```php
// \Excel::download($excel,'phones.xlsx');
\Excel::store($excel, 'tmp.xlsx');
$filename = 'phones.xlsx';
$filepath = storage_path('app/tmp.xlsx');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
flush(); // Flush system output buffer
readfile($filepath);
exit;
```

```php
namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use App\Phone;

class PhonesExport implements FromCollection
{
    protected $date;

    public function __construct($date)
    {
       $this->date = $date;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function collection()
    {
       return Phone::select('PHONES.PHONE','AREACODES.CODE')
       ->join('AREACODES','AREACODES.AREACODES_ID','=','PHONES.AREACODES_ID')
       ->where('DATE', $this->date)
       ->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't download me. If I do dd if it shows me what I need and everything. But it doesn't make me download the file, only if I press a button to download.

Comment: No, he must do the automatic download while the code is running.

If I finish executing the code and give the download button if it downloads but it is not what is needed.

Comment: Why? Are you trying to download through javascript or console?

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand why you want that but I'll edit another alternative

Comment: I explain a little.
My app is a number generator, when it generates those numbers and inserts them into the database I automatically have to export an excel file of what was generated, currently it does not download the file automatically, if it downloads if and only if I press a button to download

Comment: Yes, it worked. It just takes a while but it's what I need.